# Vertex configuration to tile repeat unit

Tags: discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, tiling, symmetry

I am working with elongated triangular tiling which has a vertex configuration of 3.3.3.4.4 and noticed that the representative symmetry is not the repeat unit.  Is there a general formula to convert symmetry to repeat tile (or specific to for semiregular tiling)?

Comment: "elongated triangular tiling", "representative symmetry", "repeat unit". Are these standard terms in the study of tilings, or are they terms you've come up with that other people might not understand?

Comment: Good question Gerry, I got them from Wiki.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Euclidean_uniform_tilings

Comment: Since posting, I still do not know the answers, but I did find http://gruze.org/tilings/semiregular by Kevin Jardine where he lists the repeat unit as translational units.

Comment: "translational unit", another term I think I've never seen.